# Android: Singleton references activity, memory leak?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-memory, appcompatactivity

First of all I'd like to say sorry if my question is dummy, I'm just starting with Android. I found some article on the web that states that the singleton that references activity is causing a memory leak.
I cannot understand how this happens!
Imagine such a situation - we have an interface called `MyInterface`, have a singleton called `MySingleton` and an activity which implements `MyInterface`

```
interface MyInterface {
   void foo();
}

class MySingleton {
  static MySingleton shared;
  MyInterface delegate;
  private MySingleton() {};

  MySingleton getShared() {
   if(shared == null)
     shared = MySingleton();
   return shared
  }

  void setDelegate(MyInterface delegate) {
   this.delegate = delegate;
  }

class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface {

 @Override
 void foo() {//do something}

 @Override
 void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     MySingleton.getShared().setDelegate(this);
     // do other setup
 }
```

Since Java doesn't have cyclic reference there shouldn't be a problem with garbage collecting `MyActivity` , or I'm wrong ? Again thanks if the question is dummy and thank you

Comment: _"there shouldn't be a problem with garbage collecting MyActivity"_ How come? `MySingleton` holds a reference to the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any memory leak happening in your code.

*In Java:*

> Memory Leak happens when Garbage Collector thinks an object is still
>   needed because it is referenced by another object.

Common Sources of memory leak:

- Anonymous Class
- Inner Classes
- Callback methods
- Static Variables with a reference to Activity or Fragment
- RxJava
- AsyncTask
- TimerTask
- Handlers
- Singleton

> If a singleton holds a reference to activity and lives longer than the
>   activity, your app faces a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation that happens because of, your activity lifecycle is longer than MySingleton, so your singleton has lifecycle as Activity, but at most situations(depends on architecture, lats lay that you have single activity app) Activity lifecycle will be as all process, or your running app.

There are planty articles about memory leaks in android. 
Check them please:

https://proandroiddev.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-memory-leaks-in-android-d7a59faaf46a

https://android.jlelse.eu/9-ways-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-android-b6d81648e35e

Comment: thanks for your answer, so If I'll override MyActivity.onDestroy and set delegate to null there then the issue should be fixed?

Comment: Yes it should help.